# Can I build Perl modules with ExtUtils::MakeMaker-based build system "out of tree"?

Tags: perl, build, autoconf, automake

Instead of adding or modifying files in the directory where the sources of a Perl module are unpacked, I would like to build everything in a separate directory. Is this easily achievable with a fairly standard `Makefile.PL` that uses `ExtUtils::MakeMaker`? (By easy, I mean something like one or a few command line parameters.) If no, does any of the other build systems support this?

**Update / Reason:** The Perl module is a binding to a library whose build system is `autoconf`/`automake`/`libtool`-based. The Perl module is shipped together with this library and calling `make` in the top directory eventually also builds the Perl library. I am interested in building the entire project in a separate build tree. At the moment I do something similar to what runrig suggested, only using symlinks. (`cp -sru $(srcdir)/. $(builddir)/.`). This has worked so far, but if there is a more elegant solution, I'd like to read about it.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  What problem are you solving?  I ask because the answer is "yes, but it will be a pain to setup and maintain".

Comment: I have updated my question. Still interested in the painful solution. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MakeMaker already copies the sources and builds them in a separate directory (that's what `blib/` is).  You can control the build location with the `INST_*` set of arguments to `WriteMakefile()`.  This example changes the location from `blib/` to `foo/`.

```
INST_ARCHLIB        => "foo/arch",
INST_LIB            => "foo/lib",
INST_BIN            => "foo/bin",
INST_SCRIPT         => "foo/script",
INST_MAN1DIR        => 'foo/man1',
INST_MAN3DIR        => 'foo/man3',
```

In addition you have to tell MakeMaker to cleanup the new build directory.

```
clean       => {
    FILES           => 'foo'
},
```

See ["Determination of Perl Library and Installation Locations"](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?ExtUtils%3a%3aMakeMaker#Determination_of_Perl_Library_and_Installation_Locations) in the [ExtUtils::MakeMaker](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?ExtUtils%3a%3aMakeMaker) docs for more info.

Answer (score 1):

```
cp -R Module-Directory-0.01 Module-Directory-0.01.copy
cd Module-Directory-0.01.copy
perl Makefile.PL
make
make test
...etc.
```

Comment: If I copy everything all the advantages of using Makefiles go away.

Comment: Timestamps get messed up, I have gone with symlinks instead (see update to question).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using symlinks:

The library to which the Perl module provides bindings uses an
`autoconf`/`automake`/`libtool`-based build system. `Makefile.PL` is
generated from `Makefile.PL.in` by `configure`. `Makefile.PL`
generates `Makefile-pl` (`Makefile` has already been taken by
`autoconf`/`automake`).

This is the relevant part of `Makefile.am`:

```
all: Makefile-pl src_deps
    $(MAKE) -f Makefile-pl

Makefile-pl: Makefile.PL
    perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=$(INSTALLDIRS) PREFIX=$(prefix)
```

I changed the second target to:

```
Makefile-pl: Makefile.PL
    -[ $(srcdir) != $(builddir) ] && cp -rsu $(abs_srcdir)/. $(builddir)/.
    perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=$(INSTALLDIRS) PREFIX=$(prefix)
```

This should work as long as building or installing the Perl module
does not result in any files being modified in-place.